# Help with new "passive" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I keep this brief and to the point.

Yesterday, I created a new tag [distance-expression](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distance-expression) and only remembered to write a short description when I read this reminder: [When you make a new tag, please write a description](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/when-you-make-a-new-tag-please-write-a-description)

The [passive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive) and [passive-voice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice) have a total of 405 posts, that's a lot to wade through if you're looking for a duplicate question, or an answer on a particular aspect of the passive voice.

So far, the **distance-expression** tag has only four questions, but before I go on a tagging spree and track down other questions that fit this tag, I would like to ask the community for advice.

1. Is there a better known, or more precise term that should be used?

In the very short description, *distance expressions* are also called **impersonal passive**, but maybe it should be changed to **passive reporting verbs**? Which name would be easier for users and learners alike?

2. Should the tag be renamed *distancing-expressions*? I think that it is a more accurate term, but maybe it's not the best or the most useful.
3. Which synonyms could be added?
4. Shouldn't the following tags, [passive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive) and [passive-voice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice), be merged? How is this done?

---

For those of you who would like to know what the hell a distancing expression is, click here: **[Passive for distancing](http://greenforest.com.ua/journal/read/passive-for-distancing-for-advanced-level)**

Comment: Related: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2478/ I need to learn more about what is possible for the community mods to do with tags. It seems like at least making passive and passive-voice synonyms would make sense, but I'll wait to see what folks say about it. Sometimes terminology is trickier than it appears.

Comment: "distance expression" sounds like it should correspond to "measure expression", and is otherwise pretty unclear. Maybe try "distancing passive" instead?

Comment: @NathanTuggy whichever is best, but I'd like there to be a general consensus before  trekking down Qs that could be tagged as such. Four Qs to retag is feasible, and quick to do, but if we run into thirty or more Qs that need retagging, then it gets to be a real pain.

Comment: I fear users would use the tag instead of [tag:expression] or [tag:distance]. Is there any reason not to use [tag:passive-voice]? Not everything in the question needs to be put in tags.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's a reasonable fear, and that is why I have asked if there a better alternative. The reason why there is a need for a subcategory, I thought I had explained in my question. I'll give a fuller explanation: Finding older questions and answers that are even related to new questions is more difficult here than on EL&U, first of all learners often don't know the correct terminology. Secondly, users who post answers often omit technical terms.

Comment: (Cont'd) Which leaves us with tags. Have you tried searching "It is thought/said /expected/hoped/believed etc.." among 405 posts? I am willing to trawl through the posts in order to group all the questions under one easy-to-find tag. There may be as many as thirty questions or as few as ten, but once tagged, we can refer to these lder questions, and with luck, close any new questions as duplicates if the answers contained in the older questions are good.

Comment: Keep in mind that tag's purpose is not finding old questions. (I imagine with the purpose of closing duplicate questions.) If that is the only purpose of a tag, then probably it's superfluous. Tags are not for such a fine search, then.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  It's an added bonus, what's wrong with finding an older question that asks the same thing and has received answers? Tags can be "followed"  by users, and it's easier to look through 30 (or even fewer) questions than 405. You seem hostile to my suggestion.

Comment: Hostile is perhaps too strong a term, but I can't come up with anything else this early in the morning.

Comment: I'm not really fond of this tag, and I think *distance* is almost sure to mislead anyone who hasn't read your explanation yet. *Distancing* is probably better than *distance*, if we're going to have a tag for this.

Comment: About your last point: Yes, I agree the two tags should be merged.  [We have a thread dedicated to this topic now](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3265/should-not-passive-voice-and-passive-be-merged), so I handled it over there.  The tags are merged.

Comment: @snailplane What about *impersonal passive*, or * passive reporting verbs* then?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's wrong that the purpose of tags is not just that. If that is the only purpose of a tag, then it should not be created.